# Are there any medieval commentators to mention the Lukan census (of Quirinius, Lk 2:2) in conjunction with the evidence from Josephus?

Tags: luke, historical-interpretation, new-testament, josephus, patristics

Josephus, of course, places this census after Herod Archelaus' exile and the creation of Iudaea Province.

So far, I've been able to find early discussion of Luke 2:2 in conjunction with Quirinius' census in Josephus by Eusebius - and then the next mention I've found isn't until John Calvin. But I'm curious if there were any commentators in between the two.

Comment: Please see the comment [**here**](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-does-luke-associate-the-birth-of-christ-with-the-census-conducted-by-quirinu/4812#4812) for a wider contextual background of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Faber Stapulensis (Lefevre d'Etaples) and Bullinger, in their respective commentaries, both point out the discrepancy. Bullinger goes into some detail and concludes that there must have been two censuses. Calvin likely read both, but goes into greater detail than either.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! This appears to be a basis for a good answer, however, at a minimum you should cite the exact references in the commentaries you note [to show your work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-does-show-your-work-mean-in-the-context-of-exegesis), and _better yet_, to quote them as well (at least in part with respect to answering the question).